# How to solve 'XXX frames skipped' problem in flutter?

Tags: flutter, error-handling, android-emulator, frame

Everything was fine before but after I ran my project on android Emulator I started getting these 'Skipped xxx frames' error.

```
__Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:57783/O6dZq3yKkk4=/ws
Syncing files to device AOSP on IA Emulator...
I/Choreographer(14845): Skipped 52 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on 
its main thread.
D/EGL_emulation(14845): eglMakeCurrent: 0xe2c05a20: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xc9bf7e00)
D/EGL_emulation(14845): eglMakeCurrent: 0xe0eca600: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe4e7fbc0)
D/eglCodecCommon(14845): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1__
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, just delete your current android emulator then create a new one. Everything will work correctly. (That worked for me!)